# How can I grab articles with the same tag, so within a template I can display those articles?

Tags: django, django-views, tags, python-3.7

I'm new to Django, so thanks for any help.
I have an Article model, and I would like to display related/similar articles by assigning tags to each article.

I've tried making a function/filter in my views.py that inherits from self (that particular article) and filters out the articles with the same tag, but with no success.

```html
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
  thumbnail = models.ImageField(max_length=200, blank=True)
  tag = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

```html
from .models import Article

class ArticleView(DetailView):
    template_name = "article/article.html"
    model = Article

    def related_articles(self):
        tagged = Article.objects.filter(tag=self.tag)
        
        return tagged
```

```html
{% if articles.objects.all %}
  {% for article in article.objects.all|related_articles %}
  <div>
    <img src="{{ article.thumbnail.url }}">
    <span>{{ article.title }}</span>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

So, whenever I try to use this filter I get no results.

Comment: Can you add the view which calls this template you posted in the question for giving us more context?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit to indicate the views.py, but it is right above the template snippet. I essentially tried to display the article itself with ArticleView(DetailView), and then make a function within the view called related_articles to get articles which share the same tag as the current article.

Comment: My bad, I read it quickly and didn't notice before commenting. But I answered a version that I think it should give you some results. And I also added an exclude to remove the article you are already seeing

Answer (score 0):

I think the `related_articles` function should be on the model class.

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
  thumbnail = models.ImageField(max_length=200, blank=True)
  tag = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

  def related_articles(self):
    tagged = Article.objects.filter(tag=self.tag).exclude(pk=self.pk)
```

Suppose your have a view like this:

```py
def articles(request):
    articles = Articles.objects.all()
    context = dict(articles=articles)

    return render(request, 'app/articles.html', context)
```

You could have a template like this:

```html
{% if articles|length %}
  {% for article in articles %}
  <div>
    <img src="{{ article.thumbnail.url }}">
    <span>{{ article.title }}</span>
    {% for related_article in article.related_articles %}
        <span>{{ related_article.title }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```